# Calculation of coordinate transformation

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, transformation

A coordinate transformation of the following matrix is to be carried out:
$$\mathbf \epsilon= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \epsilon_{11}&0&0\\ 0&
\epsilon_{22}&0\\ 0&0&\epsilon_{22}\end {array}
 \right]
 $$
This should be done with the following formula (tensor rank-2):
$$\mathbf\epsilon'=\mathbf Q \mathbf \epsilon \mathbf Q^T$$

The transformation matrix is defined as follows:
$$\,Q= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \cos(\alpha) &0&\sin(\alpha) \\ 0&1&0\\ -\sin(\alpha) &0&\cos(\alpha) \end {array}
 \right]$$
I have difficulty understanding the math for this problem. How to calculate $\mathbf\epsilon'$?

Comment: It’s just using the product of matrices.

Comment: My solution would be $$\boldsymbol\epsilon'=\left(\begin{matrix}cos^2(\alpha)\epsilon _{11}+sin^2(\alpha)\epsilon _{33}  & 0 & cos(\alpha)sin(\alpha)(\epsilon _{33}-\epsilon _{11}) \\0 & \epsilon _{22}  & 0 \\cos(\alpha)sin(\alpha)(\epsilon _{33}-\epsilon _{11}) & 0 & sin^2(\alpha)\epsilon _{11}+cos^2(\alpha)\epsilon _{33}\end{matrix}\right)$$ Could please someone confirm, if this is correct?